# Can I use https.request in vscode extension

Tags: https, proxy, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode Extension.

I have added MSTranslator as a node module because I want to call the Microsoft Translator API

but when I run the example either nothing happens,

or I get a **Error Connect EACCES**. I get this error 2 or 3 times but now it has stopped returning anything, it just jumps the code and continues

I am running this on a MacBook

```ts
if (!api_key) {
    console.log('missing api_key');
}
var params = {
    text: 'How\'s it going?',
    from: 'en',
    to: 'es'
};
var client = new MsTranslator({ api_key: api_key });
client.initialize_token(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("initialize_token", err);
        return;
    }
    client.translate(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log('error:' + err.message);
        console.log(data);
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

and when it enters `client.initialize_token` it reaches this line in MsTranslator and does nothing, just jumps out of function.

```ts
var req = https.request(self.options, function(res) {
```

My Radio Silence firewall is switched off, and the network monitor shows no activity.

If I call the same URL using the same details in `self.options` using Postman, I get back a token as expected.

Is there a problem running `https.request` within a VSCode extension, or do I have a different problem?